# Python for loop prints horizontal line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to python and can't really understand why sometimes for loop prints answer vertically or in a horizontal line

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('climate_data_Dec2017.csv')

col = ['State','9am relative humidity (%)']

hum = df[col]

grouped_by_state = hum.groupby('State')

max_hum = grouped_by_state.max()

dict = max_hum.to_dict()


for key in dict:
  print(dict[key])
```

It prints answer like

```
{'NSW': 100, 'NT': 70, 'QLD': 99, 'SA': 84, 'VIC': 98, 'WA': 89}
```

But I want to print this vertically so I've done `\n` , for loop but I couldn't make it
Any helps?

This is the answer I want

```
NSW : 100.0

NT : 70.0

QLD : 99.0

... so on
```

Comment: You shouldnt overwrite the built in dict() name. Each value in your "dict" is a dictionary itself, that is why it is printed in one line. Iterate that again and print key/values like you want. You could f.e. use  `print(*(dict[key].items()), sep="\n")` for starters - that could work. If not, use a normal loop to unroll the inner dict's items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the key and the value of a dictionary, you can include the key and the look up in the print statement.

As another commenter said, the "dict" variable should not be overwritten.

Try the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('climate_data_Dec2017.csv')

col = ['State','9am relative humidity (%)']

hum = df[col]

grouped_by_state = hum.groupby('State')

max_hum = grouped_by_state.max()

dictionary = max_hum.to_dict()


for key in dictionary:
  print(key, ": ", dictionary[key])
```

This returned the following

```
NSW :  100
NT :  70
QLD :  99
SA :  84
VIC :  98
WA :  89
```